# List blob storage by modified/upload date

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to list anything newer/older than a certain date in blob storage only? Trying to avoid listing the full container as it grows.

This has been asked before pointing to various hacks. I'm hoping Microsoft added some functionality.

Comment: As of now, it is still not possible. You will need to list all blobs and filter them on the client side.

Comment: If you want to share your idea to Microsoft, you could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to Azure storage team.